# Is it possible to make keyboard repeat on Macos act like other systems?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Currently I set

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 1
defaults write NSGlobalDomain InitialKeyRepeat -int 10
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

I'm trying to just make Macos work like every other system like Linux or Windows. Where it has clean consistent key repeat. But it seems nomatter what I press the repeat is always very clunky.

for example even with these very quick settings if I press the arrow keys on a long sentence it takes 2-3x as long as it does on windows to get to destination. But sometimes if I go faster than this it breaks the system where I press a button once and it goes crazy.

Is it possible to have the results I want and not be so clunky?

Comment: "like other systems" doesn't help to explain what you are looking for. Assuming we don't know what other systems do, can you describe what you are looking for?

Comment: OPTION + Arrow goes to the next/previous word and COMMAND + Arrow goes to beginning/end of the current line. Perhaps that helps you navigate till you find another solution?